# How to toggle a button to an active state using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 20 buttons on a page. When I click on a button I want it to switch to an `"active"` state. In this active state it will be a different color. I would like to do this using only vanilla [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [css](/questions/tagged/css).

I have the following code to create the buttons:

```
var button;
createButtons();

function createButtons() {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    //creates a new button
    button = document.createElement('Button');

    //sets correct button number and button text
    var index = i + 1;
    var text = document.createTextNode('Button ' + index);
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.className += "button";
    button.className += " default-button";
    document.body.appendChild(button);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS, eg `.button:active { color: red; }`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modern browsers support the `classList` API now.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)

In order to use the classList API, try adding the following to your code:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button')

Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    button.classList.toggle('button-active')
  })
})
```

If you want to only turn the active state on, switch the `toggle` method of classList to `add`. [Read more on classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

**Breakdown of code example:**

First I select all `.button` elements and store them in a `NodeList` data type.
Then I call array's `forEach` function (another way of doing the same would be `[].forEach.call()` but that creates new Array instance *every time it runs*). I add an event listener for click event upon which I toggle a new class name.

For a direct CSS manipulation, you can use `button.style.color = 'red'` - but I discourage you from this approach to keep your code maintainable.

Note from Phil (in the comments to this answer):
You can use `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` which shortens the line into `buttons.forEach(function (button) {`. Bear in mind that Internet Explorer does not support this.

Comment: If you're talking *"modern browsers"*, you can use [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Comment: Basic support for `Element.classList`. `.toggle()` not work for **IE10**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList.

Answer (score 1):

CSS alternative without JavaScript:

```css
input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
input[type=checkbox] + label { background-color: cyan; }
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=t1><label for=t1> Toggle 1 </label><br>
<input type=checkbox id=t2><label for=t2> Toggle 2 </label><br>
<input type=checkbox id=t3><label for=t3> Toggle 3 </label><br>
<input type=checkbox id=t4><label for=t4> Toggle 4 </label><br>
<input type=checkbox id=t5><label for=t5> Toggle 5 </label><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want one button *"active"* at a time, I would just use the CSS `:focus` / `:active` pseudo-class. For example

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  let btn = document.createElement('button')
  btn.textContent = `Button ${i}`
  btn.classList.add('button', 'default-button')
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.button:active, .button:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button.onclick = function(){ // do things here. };`
I have included the code in a snippet below. Good luck.

```js
var button;
createButtons();

function createButtons() {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    //creates a new button
    button = document.createElement('Button');

    //sets correct button number and button text
    var index = i + 1;
    var text = document.createTextNode('Button ' + index);
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.className += "button";
    button.className += " default-button";

    // --------------------------------------------------------
    // on click check if it contains the class for the color 
    // and toggle it on or off.
    button.onclick = function() {
      if (this.classList.contains("enableColor")) {
        this.classList.remove('enableColor');
      } else {
        this.classList.add("enableColor");
      }
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------
    document.body.appendChild(button);
  }
}
```

```css
.enableColor {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `-=` on a string. You are setting your button classes to `NaN`

Comment: @Phil my bad. Changed to classList.remove and classList.add

Answer (score -1):

`.focus()`, but most browsers actually block button click type behavior for security purposes. What you can do is set the button elements `disabled = true` attribute then when you get whatever action you are looking for toggle that attribute to `disabled = false`.

Here's a snippet you could adapt:

```
// enables submit button iif inputs meet validation contraints
function attachKeyupListenerToInputElements(){
    var inputs = doc.querySelectorAll('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler);
    }

    function keyupHandler() {
        if(this.value === ''){
            this.setCustomValidity('Required Field');
        } else {
            this.setCustomValidity('');
        }
        //for dialog inputs
        if(doc.querySelector(".mdc-dialog").classList.contains("mdc-dialog--open")){
            //dialog is open
            var thisSection  = this.parentElement.parentElement;
            var theseInputs = thisSection.querySelectorAll("input");
            var inputsFull = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < theseInputs.length; i++) {
                if(!theseInputs[i].checkValidity()){
                    inputsFull = false;
                }
            }
            if(inputsFull){
                doc.getElementById("dialog-accept-button").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```